# Bbq pork ribs accidentally started cooking in crock pot on warm for 2 1/2 hours before noticed

Tags: food-safety

I put country style pork ribs in my crock pot this morning with bbq sauce and didn't realize I set the control to only warm. It was not noticed until it had been on warm for about 2 1/2 hours. I immediately turned it to high.  Will they be safe to eat after cooking on high for a few hours and low for a couple more?

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on what the actual temperature for "warm" is.  If it is *above* 140F (i.e. outside of the "danger zone") you should be fine.

The limited research I've done on the "warm" temperatures of various crock pots seem to range from 145F to 200F, so it largely depends on the model.  You might want to read the manual or go to the manufacturer's web site and find out what the actual temperature for your specific model is.

However, if you can't actually find out what the warm temperature of your crock pot is, my usual rule with food safety is the proverbial "if in doubt, throw it out".  It's not worth the risk.

Comment: If the purpose of the "warm" function is to keep the contents serve-able over a long period of time, than wouldn't that require that the "warm" be outside the danger zone? Even the lowest temp in your search is above the 140 F mark for food safety.